# Connecting two sensors dht11 and dht22 the same nodemcu module esp-12e

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

I have a project where I'need connect two sensors the DHT11 and DHT22 to module nodemcu esp-12e.
Is there any way to use the two sensors in the same module at the same time?

Comment: add esp8266 to your tags to get more hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an implementation example use steps below:

- Get DHT library from https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/
- Use the code snippet below, but do not forget to set your pins :

  ```
  #include "DHT.h"
  #define DHT11PIN 2
  #define DHT22PIN 3

  DHT dht11(DHT11PIN, DHT11 );
  DHT dht22(DHT22PIN, DHT22 );

  void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("DHTxx test!");

    dht11.begin();
    dht22.begin();
  }

  void loop() {
    delay(2000);
    float h11 = dht11.readHumidity();
    float t11 = dht11.readTemperature();
    float f11 = dht11.readTemperature(true);

    float h22 = dht22.readHumidity();
    float t22 = dht22.readTemperature();
    float f22 = dht22.readTemperature(true);
    //do print them..
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice cagdas, I'll try this!

Comment: For sanity check, please follow the example : https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/blob/master/examples/DHTtester/DHTtester.ino

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is.

Both of the sensors are digital. So, as long as you have enough digital pins where ESP12e have indeed, there will not be a problem to get two different sensor data.

Just chose one data input from digital IO pins **for each**, and program it as input. You gonna need to have related data communication library. Basically, in arduino, you can do that include :

```
#include <DHT.h>
```

Check the links below to follow up :

[http://www.micropik.com/PDF/dht11.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20180328161934/http://www.micropik.com:80/PDF/dht11.pdf)

https://www.adafruit.com/product/385

Comment: I needed a real example with two sensors